# Read bits from memory c++, shift and store

Tags: c++, memory, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I'm looking to read 16 bits from memory, shift them n times in any direction, and then save back at same memory position..

Suppose that in memory position `0xfffaaa` I have:
`0101111101100001` and I want to shift it one time to right (`>>1`)
So I declare an `uint16_t` variable pointing to `0xfffaaa`.

After converting, that variable contains:
`0110000101011111` (which is 24417 in decimal).
After right shift:
`0011000010101111`      1 --> lost bit.
Which is store in memory is:
`1010111100110000` instead of:
`0010111110110000`      1---> lost bit.

Here an example how I'm trying to do it..

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    volatile uint8_t *bitmap = (uint8_t *)malloc(2);
    bitmap[0] = 0b01011111;
    bitmap[1] = 0b01100001;

    cout << bitset<8>(bitmap[0]);
    cout << bitset<8>(bitmap[1]) << '\n' << '\n';

    uint16_t* p16 = (uint16_t*)bitmap;
    cout << bitset<16>(p16[0]) << '\n';
    p16[0]>>=1;
    cout << bitset<16>(p16[0]) << '\n' << '\n';

    cout << bitset<8>(bitmap[0]);
    cout << bitset<8>(bitmap[1]) << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

And the console output is:

```
0101111101100001

0110000101011111
0011000010101111

1010111100110000
```

How can I bit shift in the way that I want working with uint16_t?

Comment: This is normal on little-endian machines. Do you need to fix it by keeping the current format of the bitmap, or is it OK to adjust its byte order?

Comment: I need to keep the bitmap format.  I can do that it works with uitn8_t insted of uitn16_t, but i need improve speed, reducing the numbers of operations, so Im trying this way (obviously I have same problem with uint32_t and uint64_t).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't with the shift, it's in how you get your data from the bitmap.

Since a shift right will move bits from bitmap[0] to bitmap[1], you can extract the data into a larger type with multiplication:

```
auto v16 = 256 * bitmap[0] | bitmap[1];
v16 >>= 1;
bitmap[0] = uint8_t(v16 / 256);
bitmap[1] = uint8_t(v16 & 255);
```

Alternatively, using only shift operations:

```
auto v16 = (bitmap[0] << 8) + bitmap[1];
v16 >>= 1;
bitmap[0] = uint8_t(v16 >> 8);
bitmap[1] = uint8_t(v16 & 0xFF);
```

Comment: The idea isn't bad, but in C++ you have native bit shift operators, you don't need to create bit shifts using multiplication and division.

Comment: @BenVoigt I've added a shift-only alternative

Comment: One last sneaky arithmetic operator survived -- bitwise OR is better than addition for assembling bytes into larger integer variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I didn't realize that I can do it I that mode. The second option fits better for my needs, and I can extend it to shift bigger buffers. I thought that, there was a form to read  plain bits from memory and shift them to reduce the time on proces.

Answer (score 0):

To know whether it is indeed faster one way or the other, you would have to run a profiler.

There are two ways to resolve your issue (if you don't include the possibility of swapping the data in the bitmap.)

1. Like @1201ProgramAlarm says:

   // get that pointer
   uint16_t* p16 = (uint16_t*)bitmap;
   uint16_t v(*p16);
   v = (v >> 8) | (v << 8); // swap
   v >>= 1;
   *p16 = (v >> 8) | (v << 8); // swap back to save in bitmap

This can be written in several different ways and you could even incorporate the shift in the swap:

```
v = (v >> 9) | (v << 7);
```

2. You don't use a p16 pointer

Since you can do the swap and shift at the same time, you can as well use your p8 directly:

```
uint61_t v((bitmap[1] >> 9) | (bitmap[0] << 7));
bitmap[0] = v >> 8;
bitmap[1] = v; // C auto-and (i.e. (v & 0xFF) is not required)
```

Note that you can't optimize much more because when you modify bitmap, you can't reload the data after it was modified. Watch out on that one.

Now, this in assembly would be optimized something like this, although it may not be the fastest (at times there are surprises when you let the C/C++ compiler do its optimization work!)

```
mov ax, [ep]  ; get current value (16 bits)
xchg al, ah
shr ax, 1     ; shift by one unsigned
xchg al, ah
mov [ep], ax  ; save result
```

For 32 and 64 bits, there is a `swapb` instruction in x86 (in 64bit too).

Note that reading & writing bytes one at a time may very well be as fast as reading 16 bits and `xchg`-ing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use union effectively:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

union joinbits
{
    uint16_t data;
    uint8_t  bits[2];
};

int main(){
    volatile uint8_t *bitmap = (uint8_t *)malloc(2);

    bitmap[0] = 0b01011111;
    bitmap[1] = 0b01100001;

    cout << bitset<8>(bitmap[0]);
    cout << bitset<8>(bitmap[1]) << '\n' << '\n';

    joinbits j;
    j.bits[1] =  bitmap[0];
    j.bits[0] =  bitmap[1];

    j.data >>= 1;

    bitmap[0] = j.bits[1];
    bitmap[1] = j.bits[0];

    cout << bitset<8>(bitmap[0]);
    cout << bitset<8>(bitmap[1]) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
0101111101100001                                                                                                                                               

0010111110110000
```